# Issue related to Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

My requirement is: There are two tables: a) `C_Table`, b) `Mst_Table`

Both have the same table structure with three columns: i) `S_NO`, ii) `CONTENT_ID`, iii) `INSTANCES`

`Mst_Table` has initially three records:

```
INSERT INTO Mst_Table Values (1, 'A1', 20);    
INSERT INTO Mst_Table Values (2, 'A2', 10);    
INSERT INTO Mst_Table Values (3, 'A3', 5);
```

Now, I am inserting four records in table C_table as:

```
INSERT INTO C_Table Values (1, 'A1', 22);    
INSERT INTO C_Table Values (2, 'A4', 20);    
INSERT INTO C_Table Values (3, 'A5', 5);    
INSERT INTO C_Table Values (4, 'A1', 18);
```

When records are inserted in table `C_table` it should check if for the column - `CONTENT_ID`, `Mst_Table` already have any record or not. If NOT then Inserts will be done successfully in `C_table`, but if YES then it will check for the column - `INSTANCES`.

if the `INSTANCES` values of `C_Table` is greater than the `Mst_Table`, then in the C_table value in the `INSTANCES` column should be UPDATED with (`INSTANCES_Value_C_Table` - `INSTANCES_Value_Mst_Table`) value.

Trigger definition:

```
create or replace trigger ANALYTICS_UPDATE_COUNT 
    after insert on C_Table referencing old as old new as new 
    for each row 

    DECLARE -- variable declarations 
    v_instance number; 
    v_count number; 

BEGIN 
    insert into temp_logger (log_text) 
    values ('-------------BEGIN-------------'); 

    -- trigger code 
    BEGIN 
         select distinct INSTANCES 
         into v_instance 
         from Mst_Table 
         where CONTENT_ID = :new.CONTENT_ID; 

    EXCEPTION 
          WHEN OTHERS 
              THEN 
                NULL; 
    END; 

    insert into temp_logger (log_text) values ('Count for ' || :new.CONTENT_ID|| ' is : '|| v_instance); 
    insert into temp_logger (log_text) values ('Difference between new and existing: ' || (:new.INSTANCES - v_instance)); 

    if ((:new.INSTANCES - v_instance) <=0 ) then 
        v_count := 0; 
    else 
        v_count := (:new.INSTANCES - v_instance); 
    end if; 

    insert into temp_logger (log_text) values ('v_count variable: ' ||v_count); 

    if v_count = 0 then 
        insert into temp_logger (log_text) values ('Inside IF'); 
        DELETE from C_Table where CONTENT_ID = :new.CONTENT_ID; 
        COMMIT; 
    else 
        insert into temp_logger (log_text) values ('Inside ELSE'); 
        UPDATE C_Table 
        set INSTANCES = v_count 
        where CONTENT_ID = :new.CONTENT_ID; 

   COMMIT; 
    end if; 

EXCEPTION 
     WHEN OTHERS 
           THEN 
              NULL; 

END;
```

Comment: Are you developing this on SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle? If not, please remove the tags that are not required. These are not like hash tags on social media.

Comment: @JonathonOgden: Thanks for the edit and suggestion, yes i will remove the hash tags. Also, i need one thing to understand, i need to add the following but am not getting the code toolbar where to edit the code:

Comment: It's added (probably some issues with syntax). Please delete comments.

Comment: @JonathonOgden: Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this your intention?

```
DROP TABLE Mst_Table
GO
DROP TABLE C_Table
GO

CREATE TABLE Mst_Table 
(
    S_NO int,
    CONTENT_ID varchar(2),
    INSTANCES int
)
GO
CREATE TABLE C_Table 
(
    S_NO int identity(1,1) not null,
    CONTENT_ID varchar(2),
    INSTANCES int
)
GO

 INSERT INTO Mst_Table Values (1, 'A1', 20);
 INSERT INTO Mst_Table Values (2, 'A2', 10);
 INSERT INTO Mst_Table Values (3, 'A3', 5); 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER VCTable ON C_Table
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO C_Table (CONTENT_ID, INSTANCES)
    SELECT inserted.CONTENT_ID, isnull(C_Table.INSTANCES - inserted.INSTANCES, inserted.INSTANCES)
    FROM inserted
    LEFT JOIN C_Table ON inserted.S_NO = C_Table.S_NO
    LEFT JOIN Mst_Table on inserted.CONTENT_ID = Mst_Table.CONTENT_ID   
END
GO

INSERT INTO C_Table (CONTENT_ID, INSTANCES) Values ('A1', 22);
INSERT INTO C_Table (CONTENT_ID, INSTANCES) Values ('A4', 20);
INSERT INTO C_Table (CONTENT_ID, INSTANCES) Values ('A5', 5);
INSERT INTO C_Table (CONTENT_ID, INSTANCES) Values ('A1', 18); 

SELECT * FROM C_Table
```

Comment: Yes, you are close to my requirement. But i do have some question on the trigger you created: 1) What is the structure of table - 'inserted'? 2) ISNULL and NULLIF are same? 3) I have not understood: INSERT INTO C_Table (CONTENT_ID, INSTANCES)
    SELECT inserted.CONTENT_ID, isnull(C_Table.INSTANCES - inserted.INSTANCES, inserted.INSTANCES)
    FROM inserted
    LEFT JOIN C_Table ON inserted.S_NO = C_Table.S_NO
    LEFT JOIN Mst_Table on inserted.CONTENT_ID = Mst_Table.CONTENT_ID

Comment: Also, 4) My requirement is basically, when I am doing an insertion in C_Table, it will check if a content_id is already available in MST_Table, if yes then it will check for the value of Instances, and if value (Instance_C_Table > Instance_Mst_Table) then in C_Table value will be updated as -- (Instance_C_Table - Instance_Mst_Table). Please let me know if at any point i am not clear.